# Adding a marker along half the distance in Maps API Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am doing an Android project using Google Maps API that gets 2 different locations and adds a marker halfway along the route.

I found out that this can be done through Javascript and Node.js, but I want to do it entirely in Google Maps API.

How can I get the distance between 2 points and add a marker half way along the route?

Thanks in advance! :D

This is the code to find the distance:

```
public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint StartP, GeoPoint EndP) {
int Radius=6371;//radius of earth in Km         
double lat1 = StartP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double lat2 = EndP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double lon1 = StartP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
double lon2 = EndP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
double valueResult= Radius*c;
double km=valueResult/1;
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
meter=valueResult%1000;
meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
Log.i("Radius Value",""+valueResult+"   KM  "+kmInDec+" Meter   "+meterInDec);
return Radius * c;
```

}

Comment: add your code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#interpolate(LatLng, LatLng, double)

in the Google Maps Android util library: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/